# Python requests.get() not working in while loop

Tags: python, https

I'm trying to create a program that will check if a URL has been updated before running the rest of the script.

I've put a get request in a while loop and I want to run the while loop until the 'LastModified' part of the request shows the URL has been updated.

When I run the code, `response` doesn't change from the initial get request outside of the while loop, but I know that the URL has been updated, so the loop continues forever.

I've printed LastUpdated and Now.date() in the for loop, both come out as expected. LastUpdated is the date from the original get request when I print in the loop. I if I stop the program and re-run it after I know URL has been updated the program works.

Can anyone help me understand why this is?

```
from requests import get

#Only run once data has been updated
response = get(endpoint, timeout=10)
LastUpdated = datetime.datetime.strptime(response.headers['Last-Modified'][5:16], "%d %b %Y").date()
Now = datetime.datetime.now()
while(LastUpdated < Now.date()):
   print("Data not updated as of " + Now.time().strftime("%H:%M") + ", last updated: " + response.headers['Last-Modified'])
   time.sleep(60)
   response = get(endpoint, timeout=10)
   LastUpdated = datetime.datetime.strptime(response.headers['Last-Modified'][5:16], "%d %b %Y").date()
```

Comment: print out LastUpdated (should be last_updated) and Now.date() in the while-loop to see what's going on.

Comment: I've printed LastUpdated and Now.date() both come out as expected. And I if I stop the program and re-run it after I know URL has been updated it works.